make TCPServer/HTTPServer not send the [FIN, PSH, ACK] packet
Have a python web server listening on port 8080, based on socketserver.TCPServer. But there are intermittent failures in the communication between the client and the server, esp. when the server sends the [FIN, PSH, ACK] packet to the client, when serving the data the client is downloading.
Network traces have been captured for both the passed runs and the failed ones.
In the passed runs, only [FIN, ACK] was sent to the client.

In the failed ones, [FIN, PSH, ACK] was sent. After that, the client would send [RST] back to the server and failed the process.

Is there a way to tune the TCPServer/HTTPServer so that the PSH packet would not be sent together with the [FIN, ACK] one? I mean, make the server deliver all the data that are requested, and only send [FIN, ACK] after that.

I don't think there's a way to control this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55403681/how-to-turn-off-tcp-psh-flag-in-the-posix-function-send

you may have to see source code for socketserver - but I think it may need to write own server from scratch. Or even it may need to create own library for socket. If you want to modify packages then it may need module scapy
